# How to take hit button or arc menu on right side of screen

Tags: android, xml, menu

I use ArcMenu Library in my project and I want set hit button 
to right of the screen,
I change the arc_menu.xml but nothing  change !!

this is arc_menu.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.capricorn.ArcLayout
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    custom:childSize="80px"
    custom:fromDegrees="270.0"
    custom:toDegrees="360.0" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/composer_button"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/control_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/composer_icn_plus"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

but every thing is from left in my layout project,
and this is my layout_ project which i use arcMenu:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:arc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <com.capricorn.ArcMenu
        android:id="@+id/arc_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        arc:fromDegrees="180"
        arc:toDegrees="270">
    </com.capricorn.ArcMenu>


</LinearLayout>
```

can anybody knows where is the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finlay I do this , by overriding the onLayout in ArcLayout class!!

if you want change of the position of hit button or child button of arcMenu

you override onLayout and onMeasure what ever you want!

onMeasure is for changing of size and onLayout is for changing position of child arcMenu

Comment: Please consider adding the code here so others may be helped by this answer.